# Continuity in $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x,y):=\begin{cases}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{|x|} + y^2} &(x,y) \neq  (0,0)\\ 0&(x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases}. $$
Show that f is continuous in $(0,0)$.
Does it suffice to say that 
$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}f(x,0) = \lim \limits_{y\to 0}f(0,y) = 0?$$
Or do I need to do something else?
Could someone present me a solution how to do this (without polar coordinates)?

Comment: No, that is not sufficient.  In order that a function of two variables **have** a limit it must be true that we get the same result taking the limit while approaching the limit point along **any** path.  Just along the two axes is not sufficient (even showing that the limit along any straight line would not be enough).  Typically, the best thing to do is to convert to polar coordinates.  That way, if the limit as r goes to 0 exists independent of $\theta$ then the limit of the function, as (x, y) goes to (0, 0), exists.

Comment: Is there a different way from using polar coordinates?

Comment: Of course.  There are always many different ways to do a problem.  But using polar coordinates is the simplest.

Comment: Could you probably present a way of doing it without polar coordinates? I need to be able to solve this problem without polar coordinates. And I am not really aware how else to show it ($\epsilon - \delta$ seems to be too complicated, and I don't know how to handle limits with two variables $\to 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the two conditions you state are not sufficient. It's easy to make examples of functions where the limit along lines through the origin is the same for all lines, but the limit doesn't exist.

In this case you can notice that
$$
-|x|\le x\le |x|
$$
so also
$$
-|x|-\sqrt{|x|}y^2\le x\le |x|+\sqrt{|x|}y^2
$$
and
$$
|x|\le \sqrt{|x|}(\sqrt{|x|}+y^2)
$$
and therefore
$$
\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{|x|}+y^2}\right|\le\sqrt{|x|}\,|y|
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to be way more complicated than I thought. So now I conclude that $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{|x|} |y| = 0$?

Comment: @lappen68 This final limit is obvious, isn't it? Then the squeeze theorem applies.

Comment: Of course it is, I was just wondering if you use "two-dimensional" limits to show continuity of two-dimensional functions.

Comment: @lappen68 You *have* to.

Comment: Alright, thanks!